# Efficiently running operations on Pandas DataFrame columns that are not unique

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a DataFrame similar to this:

```
import numpy as np
raw_data = {'Identifier':['10','10','10','11',11,'12','13']}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['Identifier'])
print df
```

As you can see the 'Identifier' column is not unique and the dataframe itself has many rows.

Everytime I try to do a calculation on the Identifier column using:

```
df['CalculatedColumn'] = df['Identifer'] + apply calculation here
```

As Identifer is not unique, is there a better way of doing this? Maybe store the calculations for each unique identifier and then pass in the results? The calculation is quite complex and added with the number of rows, this takes a long time. But i would want to reduce it as the identifiers are not unique.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you are trying to do? I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is a more pythonic way, but this works for me:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'Identifier':['10','10','10','11','11','12','13']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['Identifier'])
df['CalculatedColumn']=0

dfuni=df.drop_duplicates(['Identifier'])
dfuni['CalculatedColumn']=dfuni['Identifier']*2  # perform calculation

for j in range(len(dfuni)):
    df['CalculatedColumn'][df['Identifier']==dfuni['Identifier'].iloc[j]]=dfuni['CalculatedColumn'].iloc[j]

print df 
print dfuni
```

As an explanation: I'm creating a new dataframe `dfuni` which contains all the unique fields of your original dataframe. Then, you perform your calculation on this (I just multiplied the value of the `Identifier` by two, and because it is a string, the result is `1010`, `1111` etc.). Up to here, I like the code, but then, I'm using a loop through all the values of `dfuni` to copy them back into your original `df`. For this point, there might be a more elegant solution.

As a result, I get:

```
  Identifier CalculatedColumn
0         10             1010
1         10             1010
2         10             1010
3         11             1111
4         11             1111
5         12             1212
6         13             1313
```

PS: This code was tested with Python 3. The only thing I adapted was the print-statements. I may have missed something.